# Can anybody elaborate the meaning of following log message on Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I am trying to run the application on Mono framework which is built on windows platform. I know that there are some platform specific Interop calls are used in it. While running the application in Mono with debug I got following message. I know that it is looking for LoadLibrary but my interest is to know about "__Internal", what does this mean?

```
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: '__Internal'.
    Mono: DllImport loaded library '(null)'.
    Mono: DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
    Mono: Searching for 'LoadLibrary'.
    Mono: Probing 'LoadLibrary'.
    Mono: Probing 'LoadLibrary'.
    Mono: Probing 'LoadLibraryA'.
    Mono: Probing 'LoadLibraryA'.
    Mono: DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
    Mono: Searching for 'GetProcAddress'.
    Mono: Probing 'GetProcAddress'.
    Mono: Probing 'GetProcAddress'.
    Mono: Probing 'GetProcAddressA'.
    Mono: Probing 'GetProcAddressA'.
    Mono: DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
    Mono: Searching for 'FreeLibrary'.
    Mono: Probing 'FreeLibrary'.
    Mono: Probing 'FreeLibrary'.
    Mono: Probing 'FreeLibraryA'.
    Mono: Probing 'FreeLibraryA'.
    Mono: DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
    Mono: Searching for 'LoadLibrary'.
    Mono: Probing 'LoadLibrary'.
    Mono: Probing 'LoadLibrary'.
    Mono: Probing 'LoadLibraryA'.
    Mono: Probing 'LoadLibraryA'.
```

With Best Regards,
Omky

Answer (score 3):

It is the name of the DLL that's being searched for the function.  That would normally be "kernel32.dll" to find LoadLibrary() but Mono also supports the special name `"__Internal"`.  Which makes it look for the exported function in DLLs that are already loaded.  A feature that was originally intended for [embedding Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono) in an unmanaged program.

It works on Windows, even if Mono is not embedded.  Kernel32.dll is *always* loaded since it is required to get the process running.  So the likely [DllImport] directive was:

```
[DllImport ("__Internal", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern bool LoadLibrary(string path);
```